# JSON по шаблону с DF

Tags: python, pandas

Есть шаблон JSON

```
{
  "active": "ON",
  "name": "$name",
  "data": {
    "objects": [
      {
        "type": "ip",
        "value": "$value"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Пытаюсь заполнить его с

```
pd.DataFrame({'name': ['first_line', 'second_line'], 'value': ['11','100;200']})


    name    value
0   first_line  11
1   second_line     100;200
```

Проблема в том, что не получается сделать JSON когда значений в ячейке несколько.

Пример с данной таблицей:

```
[{
  "active": "ON",
  "name": "first_line",
  "data": {
    "objects": [
      {
        "type": "ip",
        "value": "11"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "active": "ON",
  "name": "second_line",
  "data": {
    "objects": [
      {
        "type": "ip",
        "value": "200"
      },
      {
        "type": "ip",
        "value": "100"
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
```

Возможно ли такое получить?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сформировать json из датафрейма по шаблону? Приведите пример такого "проблемного" датафрейма плюс ваш код, которым вы заполняете шаблон.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

tmp = (df
       .assign(value=df["value"].str.split(";"))
       .explode("value")
       .assign(type="ip")
       .groupby("name")
       .apply(lambda x: x.drop(columns="name").to_dict("records"))
       .to_dict())

res = [
    {"active": "ON", "name": key, "data": { "objects": val }}
    for key, val in tmp.items()
]

pprint(res)
```

отформатированный результат:

```
In [39]: print(json.dumps(res, indent=2))
[
  {
    "active": "ON",
    "name": "first_line",
    "data": {
      "objects": [
        {
          "value": "11",
          "type": "ip"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "active": "ON",
    "name": "second_line",
    "data": {
      "objects": [
        {
          "value": "100",
          "type": "ip"
        },
        {
          "value": "200",
          "type": "ip"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: спасибо Вам большое. Я правильно понял, что нужно сначала так сказать "раскрыть" ячейку, сделав дополнительные строки и потом уже проходиться по ним?

Comment: @user433816, да, вы можете запустить `df.assign(value=df["value"].str.split(";")).explode("value")`, чтобы понять как это работает

Comment: конечно,  я каждую команду по отдельности запустил.

Answer (score 0):

А если будет + столбец

Например

```
    name          value      value_1
0   first_line    11         XXX;ZZZ
1   second_line   100;200    YYY
```

```
[{
  "active": "ON",
  "name": "first_line",
  "data": {
    "objects": [
      {
        "type": "ip",
        "value": "11"
      }
    ]
  },
  "data_1": {
    "objects_1": [
      {
        "type": "ip",
        "value": "XXX"
      },
      {
        "type": "ip",
        "value": "ZZZ"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "active": "ON",
  "name": "second_line",
  "data": {
    "objects": [
      {
        "type": "ip",
        "value": "200"
      },
      {
        "type": "ip",
        "value": "100"
      }
    ]
  },
  "data_1": {
    "objects_1": [
      {
        "type": "ip",
        "value": "YYY"
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
```